# Java: Convert lat/lon from EPSG:4236 to EPSG: 3857

Tags: java, projection, geotools

How would I convert my lat lon to EPSG 3857 projection using geotools or another java library?  I'm having trouble finding the proper methods to use.  I know OpenLayers (javascript) can do it easily, but I don't see a clear path to getting these coordinates transformed.

```
I would like to see this transformation
source lon, lat: -71.017942,  42.366662    
destination lon, lat: -71 1.25820, 42 22.0932
```

So I have created my CRS

```
final CoordinateReferenceSystem source = CRS.decode( "EPSG:4236" );
final CoordinateReferenceSystem dest = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857");

final MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(source, dest);
```

But creating geometries doesn't seem straight forward with the points, as they are requiring a geometry factory or something..

I'm new to geo tools and geospatial data, thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution for you:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4236");
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857");
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, false);
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(lon, lat));
Point targetPoint = (Point) JTS.transform(point, transform);
```

Comment: a bit late but your sourceCRS is wrong (4326 -> 4236)

Comment: @dwana fixed :)